# How can I set a Horizontal! scroll bar for my Github page under this bootstrap theme?

Tags: html, css, github, scrollbar

[here is my page](http://hypergroups.github.io/2013/09/06/Diagonize---test/)

the code is

```
<pre class="Input" style="
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 66px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
padding: 8px;
overflow:scroll;
"><code>p =     Orthogonalize[engenvectors]ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</code></pre>
```

How ever I didn't add the auto word-wrap in my raw html file, and I wanna see the effect like that in StackExchange.

```
    Orthogonalize[engenvectors]ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
```

It seems that the theme's css override the setting in raw html file.

So how to solve the problem.

The raw effect of horizontal scroll bar is shown by the following picture.
[image]

There is a problem, The bootstrap theme changed the horizontal scroll bar into a vertical scroll bar, the horizontal scroll bar doesn't take effect.

Seems the theme's "word-wrap" prevent the horizontal scroll take effect, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS: (Might as well try it directly on the `<code>` tag and see what you get..

```
pre.input {
     white-space:pre;
     overflow-x:scroll;
     background-color:#EEE;
     vertical-align:baseline;
     font-family:Monospace;
}
code {
     white-space:pre;
     overflow-x:scroll;
     overflow-y: none; /* add this line */
     background-color:#EEE;
     vertical-align:baseline;
     font-family:Monospace;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean put this in my theme's css? or modify the existed css code?

Comment: Try both. Add it to the external CSS stylesheet first. If that doesn't work, try placing it inline.

Comment: `<pre class="Input" style="
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 66px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 8px;

white-space:pre;
overflow-x:scroll;
background-color:#EEE;
vertical-align:baseline;
font-family:Monospace;
">` I've tried this, doesn't work well.

Comment: I've tried add that into the `bootstrap.min.css` file, still doesn't work well.

Comment: Without seeing every bit of your code, There's no way I can tell you what other CSS properties my be over-riding these. Besides, isn't your `class="Input"` supposed to be `class="input"`? Classes are case-sensitive.

Comment: No, the "Input" class doesn't take effect here, because I delete the .css file.

Comment: The problem is The theme changed the horizontal scroll bar into a vertical scroll bar.

Comment: Failed, Seems the theme's word wrap prevent it take effect, I guess, I've tried, word-wrap: none; word-break:none; also failed.

Comment: The problem is trying to find the correct place for the CSS so inheritance doesn't play a part. Why don't you create a new stylesheet and add it to the end of the list of sheets being loaded. Then use your Web Dev Tools to see what the heck is going on.